# ModuleNotFoundError for Drake in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter, drake

I've installed pydrake using pip in a virtual environment

```bash
$ python3 -m venv drakeEnv
$ drakeEnv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
$ drakeEnv/bin/pip install drake
$ source env/bin/activate
(drakeEnv) $ pip install jupyter
(drakeEnv) $ pip install ipython
(drakeEnv) $ ipython kernel install --name=drakeEnv
(drakeEnv) $ jupyter notebook
```

Even though the `drakeEnv`shows up Jupyter's list of kernels, I still get
*ModuleNotFoundError: No moudule named 'pydrake'*. When I'm in the *drakeEnv* environment, then running `which jupyter` tells me that I'm not running the global Jupyter installation, so what is the problem ?

I'm trying to run this from Ubuntu Yammy 20.04

EDIT: the activation command on the fourth line has a typo

Comment: What I see above is that you hadn't activated the drakeEnv when you installed drake. So it wasn't in that environment as you seem to find? Another way to say this is [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/): "Before you can start installing or using packages in your virtual environment you’ll need to activate it." Alternative to working this out is to run `%pip install drake` from inside the notebook where you want to import it. After it run successfully, restart the kernel and try the import statement. Note the magic `%` symbol.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear. specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your commands.

The `source env/bin/activate` fails:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
bash: env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

I assume this was a typo pasting into StackOverflow and it should have been `drakeEnv/bin/activate`, so I did that and continued.

Then I got to this command:

```
(drakeEnv) $ ipython kernel install --name=drakeEnv
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'
```

So that command is clearly wrong, so I skipped it.  I was still able to run

```
(drakeEnv) $ jupyter notebook
```

And then create a new notebook and `import pydrake` successfully.

So whatever went wrong for you, I think maybe your list of steps to demonstrate it is not an accurate depiction of what you actually tried.

Comment: I guess the `ipython kernel install ` step was wrong.